# Two list compare in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two list, first one with names only and second one with names and values corresponding to names.
What I am trying to achieve is to find in second list all names that presented in first list with its values in second one.
I tried this way, but missing the corresponding numbers

```
matches = []
for i in list(first):
    if i in list(second]):
       matches.append(i)
```

Plz Help

Comment: if it has names and values corresponding to names - it is not a list, but dict or pd.Dataframe. Pls update the question with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it has names and values corresponding to names - it is not a list, but dict or pd.DataFrame

for pd.DataFrame:

```
matches = list2[list2.name.isin (list1)]
```

for dict:

```
matches = {}
for i, v in dict2.items():
    if i in list1:
       matches[i] = v
```

or just `matches = {i:v for i in dict2 if i in list1}`